# Where to check and delete google_experiment_mod from website

Tags: local-storage

When I go to inspection elements in chrome or firefox, it says there in "local storage" that there are two items "google_experiment_mod" and "google_experiment_mod3".

After some research it seems to be about google adsense that my website had in the past, but not anymore. I don´t find anything in the code of the website related to that, or anything related with "local storage".

Can anyone help me understand how to search and find any old code that might need to be removed from my website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

investigating chrome memory i found this
http://prntscr.com/mc7uno